# issues on closing a form within the form constructor in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

My requirement is I need to close the form before the form was displaying if it is not satisfied some condition. For that I written shown event but it is working at one place that is shown in the code

the code i written is

```
public form1()
{
   Initialize component();
   if(some condition)
   {
      if(some condition)
      {
             if(some condition)
             {
             }
             else
             {
              this.Shown += new EventHandler(MyForm_CloseOnStart);//here form is displaying event is not working
             }
      }
      else
      {
         this.Shown += new EventHandler(MyForm_CloseOnStart);//here only form is closing before displaying the form
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if(some condition)
      {}
      else
      {this.Shown += new EventHandler(MyForm_CloseOnStart);}//here form is displaying shown event is not working

   }

}
    public void MyForm_CloseOnStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Please rephrase it.

Comment: @Yamuna Pattem  make your question clear. Only then we can answer.

Comment: @yamuna 1.) your question itself is unclear you REALLY should rephrase it and best include a diagram of the actions you want.   2.) The code shown is.....lets call it interesting you are checking 3 times in a row if the same condition is true without any possible changes to it in between and in addition to this also use the smae condition in the else path..........I SINCERLY hope that that condition is only meant as a place holder else I would suggest reading up on if statements as taht is absolutely illogical codewise.

Comment: You cannot close a form until the Load event runs.  You could consider throwing an exception in your constructor.  The client code then knows that calling Show() isn't desirable.  Or move the Show() call into a public method of the Form class.  Or move the condition code into a separate static method so the client knows not to create the form object at all.  Plenty of choices, you'll have to pick your favorite.

Comment: instead os shown i given load event also but that is working fine at one place only

Comment: It will be better, if possible, to check the condition before creating a new form1

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that I want to close my form based on the value of flag variable. then:

```
    public Form1(Boolean flag)
    {
        try
        {
            if (flag)
                InitializeComponent();
            else
                Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {  
        }

    }
```